# IPP Customer Object as Non Taxable

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Looking for clarification / final answer:

Reference question: https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=87&threadid=16477

```
What's the proper way to edit a customer and make them non-taxable? 

If you set SalesTaxCodeId to "0" you get: 
Error validating Sales Tax Code ID:Invalid integer. 

If you set SalesTaxCodeId to "" the customer becomes taxable. 

If you omit SalesTaxCodeId, the customer becomes taxable. 

The docs say "If the field value is null, the job is not taxable. ", but that doesn't seem to be the case. 

We have been setting SalesTaxCodeId to "" in the past, but it looks like this no longer works. Code is attached. 

What's the right way? 

Paul
```

It was noted at the issue was a bug and Paul noted it has since been fixed. For clarification, in order to set a customer as non-taxable, the SalesTaxCodeId / SalesTaxCodeName must be null fields?

Ex.

`...

<SalesTaxCodeId />

<SalesTaxCodeName />

...`

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation:

QBO only supports the customers or jobs being taxable or not, so if this field is "1", the job is taxable. If the field value is null, the job is not taxable. All other values are invalid.
Note that if you have specified a TaxAmt and TaxRate, SalesTaxCodeId will be "1" even if you don't specify it directly.

> **To make SalesTaxCodeId not taxable, TaxAmt and TaxRate must be null.**

thanks,
Jarred

Comment: Jared, is this the same for QBD connections and we are correct in assuming a null tag would be `<SalesTaxCodeId />`?